# How can I populate a TableViewCell LeftDetail?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview

I have fetched an object from my CoreData and had it stored in an array, the prototype cell im using is the leftDetail and I would like to populate the cells in my TableView with the attribute content as my Title and the Attribute key as the left detail. Just like the contacts app.

How can it be done?

this is how I am setting up my cell content:

```
 if (matchingData.count <= 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"no item found";
}
else {
    NSString *displayData;
    for (NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData) {
        displayData = [obj valueForKey:@"Name"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = displayData;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";

      }
   }
```

but that only will give me one and one title for the left detail.

Answer (score 0):

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you just need to set:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = yourText;
```